# Spring JPA @OneToMany Parameter value [] did not match expected type

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I get this error when requesting service line:

```
List<Order> orders = ordersRepository.getByCustomerId(id);
```

Error:
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [5] did not match expected type [nz.webshop.models.Customer.Customers (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [5] did not match expected type [nz.webshop.models.Customer.Customers (n/a)]

Repository:

```
public interface OrdersRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Integer> {
    List <Order> getByCustomerId(Integer customerId);
}
```

Entities:

```
@EntityA:
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order {
@ManyToOne(targetEntity=Customers.class)
   @JoinColumn (name = "customer_id", referencedColumnName="customer_id")
    private Integer customerId;

...getters/setters




@EntityB:
@Table (name ="customer")
public class Customers {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    private Integer customerId;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Order.class, mappedBy = "customerId")
    private List<Order> Order;

...getters/setters
```

Where tables are like this:

```
CREATE TABLE orders
(
  order_id           INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  customer_id INT,
 FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customer (customer_id)
);


CREATE TABLE customer
(
  customer_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name  VARCHAR(50) ,
  last_name   VARCHAR(50) 

    );
```

Update:
I changed EntityA as follows:

```
@EntityA:
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order {

@Column(name = "customer_id") 
private Integer customerId;

@ManyToOne(targetEntity=Customers.class)
    private Customer customer;

...getters/setters
```

But then when requesting the same service line new error: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet.  Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'order0_.customer_customer_id' in 'field list'.

Where is the problem could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the Order.customerId property is not set up correctly. You're requesting that ManyToOne find Customer models based on their IDs, but then you're loading the models as Integers. Try this instead:

```java
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", referencedColumnName="customer_id")
private Customer customer;
```

Let me know if this works, and if not, we can troubleshoot some more.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it and changed like you suggested but  the app do not want to run it, even nothing is marked red. I also made a field customer_id in my entity Order: I  inserted   @Column(name = "customer_id")
    private Integer customerId; It say: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory

Comment: I changed a bit removed line @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", referencedColumnName="customer_id"). And it runs, but then when requesting the same service line new error: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Comment: Ok, I think I understand your problem a little better. Your repository method relies on customerId, but you are specifying a ManyToOne JoinColumn, which doesn't result in an Integer. Try using the Integer type with Column only (not ManyToOne/JoinColumn).

Comment: I tried it: in Order entity I have those: @Column(name = "customer_id") private Integer customerId and  @ManyToOne(targetEntity=Customers.class)
   private Customers customer; same error: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a];  Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'order0_.customer_customer_id' in 'field list'

Comment: Can you copy/paste your full code in the original post? It would make it easier to read

Comment: I cannot do it in original question, because it will be another question with a different code and different error. I only changed EntityA to following: @Column(name = "customer_id") private Integer customerId;  @ManyToOne(targetEntity=Customers.class) private Customers customer;  ...getters/setters

Comment: Actually I added new code a new error message as an update in the question field.

Comment: When changed all as you suggested and also removed the integer field customerID from entityA it worked!